# RadioButton Image

Tags: android, radio-button

How would I modify the .xml and .java files so that a RadioButton shows one image when selected and another image when not selected?

Example for RadioButton I am learning from: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-radiobutton-example/

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://heliodorj.blogspot.com/2009/04/androids-statelistdrawable-example.html) is an example that uses StateListDrawable and RadioButtons, and seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set its [`android:button`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#CompoundButton) property to a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) that has at least two states: selected=true and a default one (unselected).